# Хочу вывести ключ из таблицы mysql, но он идет посимвольно с каждой строки

Tags: php, html5

Делаю авторизацию на php, нашел в интернете код, и решил немного 'Модифицировать' его созданием ролей. Создал в базе данных еще один столбец с элементом либо 0 либо 1. Где 1 это администратор. Проверяю через print_r все выводиться и ключи и значения строки. Вызываю ее через foreach и он идет посимвольно с каждого столбца таблицы.
Код PHP

```
    $link=$db;

if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) and isset($_COOKIE['hash']))
{
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *,INET_NTOA(user_ip) AS user_ip FROM users WHERE user_id = '".intval($_COOKIE['id'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $userdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    if(($userdata['user_hash'] !== $_COOKIE['hash']) or ($userdata['user_id'] !== $_COOKIE['id'])
 or (($userdata['user_ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])  and ($userdata['user_ip'] !== "0")))
    {
        setcookie("id", "", time() - 3600*24*30*12, "/");
        setcookie("hash", "", time() - 3600*24*30*12, "/", null, null, true); // httponly !!!
        print "Хм, что-то не получилось";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Привет, ".$userdata['user_login'].". Всё работает!";
    }
}
else
{
    header("refresh: 0.2; login.php");
   
};
    $row = array_values($userdata);
    print_r($row);
?>
```

Далле идет код вызова из таблицы.

```
<table class="user user<?php foreach ($row as $user) : ?><?php echo $user[5]; ?><?php endforeach; ?>">
```

В итоге в row у нас есть ключи. Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => TraenGO [2] => b7a6c281292c1b3c3c7c35afc7f1aa18 [3] => 8c5e49bc0e310330d30a9f94fc6b783d [4] => 127.0.0.1 [5] => 1 )

А при вызове 5го ключа, я получаю "G29." Это каждый 5й символ каждого столбца. Как можно это решить, можно ли напрямую вызвать 5й столбец а не символ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `$row[5]` очевидно.

Comment: u_mulder Спасибо вам большое.